# Trying to INSERT to based on CASE statement with SELECT VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, insert

I Have a list of of SpellIDs with corresponding M values.
Given by the statement

```
SELECT TOP(1000) Spell_ID, MAX(Episode_Order) as M
From [dbo].[Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing]
GROUP BY Spell_ID
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecukc.png)

What I want to is to INSERT on the Episode Order Column on my Inpatients_episodes_table, a value depending on the M column from the select statement, on the corresponding spell_IDs. (Each row has a spell ID and Episode order value)

The logic is:For each spell ID value in the table Check the corresponding spellID in the select statement and -> check M value. Then Compare M value from the select statement to the Episode Order value from the table. Based on this comparison, insert either a discharge or admittance code

I am trying to relate the select statement and the table both on spell_IDs, but I'm not too how.

So far I have this:

```
UPDATE Inpatient_Episodes_Landing SET Episode_Ward = Null;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Inpatient_Episodes_Landing] ([Episode_Ward])
SELECT
(Case when Episode_Order=01 then Admission_Ward_Code
            when Episode_Order = (SELECT Spell_ID, MAX(Episode_Order) as M
                                From [dbo].[Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing] 
                                where Spell_ID = (select SpellID from [dbo].[Inpatient_Episodes_Landing])
                                GROUP BY Spell_ID ) then Discharge_Ward_Code
            else Admission_Ward_Code
END)
FROM [dbo].[Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing]
Select TOP (1000) SpellID,Episode_Number,Episode_Ward from Inpatient_Episodes_Landing
```

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I can't tell if you want an `update` or `insert`.  You don't explain all the logic in the code you have -- and your problem status suggests much simpler code.

Comment: The subquery in your case expression will certainly fail at some point. That subquery MUST return a single row containing a single value. That attempt to correlate it with the outer query will not work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just updated the logic of the problem, hope it's now more clear